# Advertise self as ipv6 dns server, with ra-pd / radvd

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, radvd

I use prefix delegation to set up stateless IPv6 on my local network. On my router, my RADVD setup looks like this:

```sh
$ cat /etc/radvd.conf 
interface lan {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix ::/64 {  };
    # Google Public DNS
    RDNSS 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844 { };
};
```

As you can tell I advertise Google's public DNS for IPv6, and things current work fine. There's `option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;` in `dhcdpd.conf` for the IPv4 side of things.

Now I considered experimenting with pihole: running my own DNS server on the router. The IPv4 address of the router is static so I know how to advertise the router as the DNS server on the IPv4-side of things (`option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;`).

But I'm unsure of how to do that on the IPv6 side. So far I completely avoided setting static IPv6 addresses (`wide-dhcpv6` gives me a prefix from my ISP, and sets the router's lan address to `${prefix_48}:0000::1`). I wonder if there's a way to keep on doing this and never manually assign IPv6 addresses.

Something like `RDNSS ::/64 { }; # advertise self as DNS server`.

Does this setup make sense?

Or would you simply assign a manual unique-link-local address on the router and advertise that? (`fd` prefix)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet supported, corresponding Feature Request here: https://github.com/radvd-project/radvd/issues/126